# How to share common libraries in Jboss7

Tags: jboss7.x

**Hi friends**,

i have more than one **WAR** in my server, each war has some common libraries(.jar). How to share the common libraries in JBoss7. please anybody help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Created a directory : mkdir -p JBoss_HOME/modules/com/common/lib/main
2. Placed all jars inside main dir
3. Created module.xml under main dir.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.common.lib">
>     <resources>
>         <resource-root path="JarName-1.0.1.jar"/>
>     </resources>
> </module>
> ```

4. Created jboss-deployment-structure under WEB-INF & packed the war deployment file.

> ```
>     <jboss-deployment-structure>
>        <deployment>
>           <dependencies>
>              <module name="com.comman.lib"/>
>           </dependencies>
>        </deployment>
>     </jboss-deployment-structure>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom module of common jar files and add application dependency(war) on custom module through jboss-deployment-structure.xml file

Comment: Thanks Abhijit Humbe,

Comment: please give explanation about custom module, How to create that custom module and jboss-deployment-structure.xml where to save this.